# Как вернуть bool/string/other если внутри происходит работа с await?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Ключевое слово `async` перед функцией гарантирует, что эта функция в любом случае вернёт промис.

Что делать если необходимо сделать функцию которая что-то чекает, должна вернуть не промис, но она опирается на результат работы аякс запроса или нескольких?
Нужно, чтобы функция возвращала например `void` или `bool`/`string`/`object` или любой другой результат, но при этом внутри себя содержала `await`?

Как пример (не смотрите на проверку прав пользователя, это просто пример, можно подставить что угодно):

```
let userHasPermission = () => {
    let result = // await тут обращение к серверу в ожидании проверки
    
    return result.hasPermission;
};

let showButtons = () => {
    if (userHasPermission())
        btn.show();
}

showButtons();
```

Писать `userHasPermission().then(() => { btn.show(); } )` ?

Можно ли как-то без then? Чтобы было наглядное `if (что-то)`, и возврат не промис в функции с await?

Comment: Нельзя. Никак нельзя. Вообще нельзя.

Comment: @AlexeyTen не дубликат. Я знаю как возвращать значения. Я знаю теорию. Тут другое.

Comment: @AlexeyTen получается только лепить всякие неудобные фигни типа then? вся удобочитаемость кода в итоге пропадает((  получается можно только писать `if (await userHasPermission()) {  ...   }`  или `userHasPermission().then(...)` ?

Comment: Для удобочитаемости придумали async/await, но то всё равно асинхронные промизв под капотом и с этим ничего сделать нельзя

Comment: а чем `if (await userHasPermission())` неудобно? Наоборот, очень удобно и наглядно!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko в целом-то да)  (на самом деле я только при написании комментарии об этом вспомнил))).  Просто у меня договорённость в команде что мы с запроса всегда возвращаем json и поэтому у меня скорее получится вот так: `if (await userHasPermission().hasPermission)`, т.е. другой метод будет знать о том, что должны вернуть в предыдущем методе. Можно ли как-то этот момент вырулить?))

Comment: можете вернуть `hasPermission` из функции `userHasPermission`. У вас кстати в вопросе в коде так и написано :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko но ведь функция возвращает промис)) попробую уточнить, то есть можно писать `return result` и  `if (await userHasPermission().hasPermission)` а можно `return result.hasPermission;` и `if (await userHasPermission())` ? если второе возможно, тогда уже становится круто)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko что-то такое получится как я понимаю https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj0Ut.png - два async и три await))  как-то криповенько, но думаю это норма))

Comment: `await userHasPermission().hasPermission` !== `(await userHasPermission()).hasPermission`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так можно использовать - красиво и наглядно. Возвращать из `userHasPermission` сразу `hasPermission`.

```js
//emulating AJAX request
let getUser = async() => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({
    hasPermission: true
  }), 3000));
}

let userHasPermission = async() => {
  let result = await getUser();
  return result.hasPermission;
};

let showButtons = async() => {
  if (await userHasPermission())
    console.log('btn show');
}

console.log('will show "btn show" after 3 seconds');
showButtons();
```